# How to hide Dock on non-fullscreen desktop

Tags: macos, dock, desktop, fullscreen

I want to hide Dock on non-full desktops. It takes a lot of space so some applications are hard to use in such small amount of space, but on the other hand I don't want to keep each single application on its own desktop, because of logical grouping.

So is there any way to hide dock and make program take extra space used by Dock. like on the full-screen desktop but keeping multiple applications.

I would be grateful for any help.
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide/show the **Dock** by pressing <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> which checks/un-checks the **Automatically hide and show the Dock** checkbox under **System Preferences** > **Dock**, and then application windows can occupy the space normally used by the **Dock**.

When hidden, you can have the **Dock** temporarily reappear by moving the mouse to the bottom of the screen (*that's assuming you have it in its default location*).

Comment: Thx, I missed this option.